# Limit bone animation velocity

Tags: animation, armature, bones, physics

I'm currently animating a robot arm. For this purpose, I created an armature with IK solver. I've constraint the bone (aka robot joint) transform to match the motion possible with the robot.

However, what I couldn't find, was a constraint to limit the animation velocity and acceleration of a bone. Is this even possible with Blender?

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody answers, I found a temporary solution:

The iTaSC IK solver features some velocity constraints: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/rigging/armatures/posing/bone_constraints/inverse_kinematics/introduction.html